# Function outside main not returning proper value from For Loop

Tags: c, for-loop, visual-studio-2015

For some inexplicable reason I'm not doing to good with the syntax in C. Let me cut to the specifics and explain what I'm having trouble with.

Get user input integer in main, send the integer to a function where it uses a 'for loop' to count up to that number.

Problem: I can't get a proper return value up in main. The loop works ok but the function of the loop returns a 0. I'm stuck here. Have made several tweaks back and forth, researched for proper syntax but I can't get it exactly how it's supposed to be.

```
int forLoop(int input); //function//

int main(){
    int input;
    printf("Enter an integer \n");
    scanf_s("%d", &input);
    printf("Results %d ex: 1 2 3...8 ", forLoop(input));

    return 0;
}//end here//

int forLoop(int input){ //function//

    for (int i= 0  ; i < input; ) {
        printf("%d \n", i = i + 1);     

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What did you expect as output? If I give number `5`, I get `1 2 3 4 5`.

Comment: `return 0;` ----> `return i;`.....?

Comment: You have a `return 0;` right there at the end of the function, why would you expect it to return anything else!?

Comment: @LPs or, maybe `return --i;`, considering 0-indexing?

Comment: @SouravGhosh - Why return the result of a store operation to a local variable? :)

Comment: ....and `for (int i= 0  ; i < input; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", i);     

    }`  would be better

Comment: @StoryTeller to get the count, maybe? That's not wrong, however. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh - No, it's not wrong. Just a wasted store operation :)

Comment: @StoryTeller that is why I put the  _"maybe"_ part. :)

Comment: @StoryTeller I can't put **i** for the result to come up in main. Only '0' has worked. Have tried other tweaks, not worked.

Comment: CORRECTION; all I had to do was declare **i** before the for loop. However I end up getting the same thing as **input**  but not the full execution display in main.

Answer (score 2):

The function returns zero because you typed `return 0;` in it.

Instead, do this:

```
int forLoop (int input){
    int i;
    for (i= 0; i < input; i++) {
        printf("%d \n", i);     

    }
    return i; // will be the same value as "input"
}
```

Comment: That's correct ! Totally missed the idea of declaring **i** before the loop. However, it returns only the 5 aka input or final number. How can I make it display the full execution from the function `1 2 3 4 5` ??

Comment: @EddardPeartree You print the numbers (0-4) inside the function so that's what it does already.

Comment: Ok, but would it work that way if I called the function at any other point in main?

Comment: @EddardPeartree Yes.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Lundin !